# Probability of getting an $8$-digit number that has more prime digits than non-prime digits.

Tags: probability

What is the probability of getting an $8$-digit number that has **more** prime digits than non-prime digits.

I consider the prime digits to be: $2,3,5$ and $7$.

I know that the first digit should not be zero so I divide to 2 cases:

First case we say the first digit is prime then from the other seven we must choose $4,5,6,7$ to be prime, in order that there will be more prime digits than non-prime

$\ \frac{4}{9}\sum\limits_{n=4}^7\binom{7}{n}(\frac{2}{5})^n(\frac{3}{5})^{(7-n)}\tag1$

Second case we say the first digit is non-prime then from the other seven we must choose $5,6,7$ to be prime, in order that there will be more prime digits than non-prime.

$\ \frac{5}{9}\sum\limits_{n=5}^7\binom{7}{n}(\frac{2}{5})^n(\frac{3}{5})^{(7-n)}\tag2$

We take the sum of $(1)$ and $(2)$ and that's the answer. Is it true?

Comment: A small request: can you explain the cases $1$ and $2$ in more detail? I  am not able to understand how you derived the above stated binomial expressions.

Comment: It looks right to me.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг I edited my answer to explain the cases

Comment: Perfect. Thank you for the elaboration, your answer seems correct to me.

Comment: I am number 3 that calls it correct. Now start estimating the probability that it is ;).